# What kernel for ARM architechture, Linux or BSD?

Tags: linux, kernel, arm, gnu, bsd

I'm a computer sciences student and recently started a project with the engineering department that involves an onboard ARM processor, the question is what sort of operating system, kernel and filesystem, is recommended for such case. I'm sure that the best idea would be to develop our own system, so we can save the processor and memory resources, but this is mainly for testing and establishing the system needs and capabilities, so for that purpose, what operating system is recommended and why?

Thank you for you help,

Colin.

Comment: Please tell us things more specific about the project, its purpose and other things such as whether it will have any real time restrictions, etc.

Comment: Well the project aims to a build a nanosat so we have lots of restriction but at the moment we are just testing to find a solution that will fit our needs and then actively work and develop the system, we  want to see the real capacities of the ARM architecture together with a UNIX or UNIX like operating system.

Comment: Whichever you're most familiar with among the ones that support your hardware.

Comment: Gilles comment is totally pertinent, and David's answer has been very helpful for this question can be closed.

Answer (score 1):

If you prefer a kernel for embedded devices or system with real-time restrictions I would choose the Linux kernel or any other related version for embedded or real-time. But this is only my opinion. Searching a little I found this [slides](http://www.slideshare.net/mahendram/comparison-of-netbsd-and-linux) which can help you to decide.